# Nesting commands in windows batch file and Parsing results recursively

Tags: windows, batch-file

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbAbF.png)

I am trying to fetch all registry entries under 
`HKEY_Local_Machine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` and Delete if `REG_EXPAND_SZ` key contains value `C:\Users\sas-`

Ideal Steps Script should do :

1) Get all Registry entries for users Using :

```
reg query "HKEY_Local_Machine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" 
    >> xyz.txt
```

2)If users name is sas-### (which we can get in "REG_EXPAND_SZ") then delete this entry :

```
for /f "skip=10 tokens=* " %%a in (xyz.txt) do (
       for /f "eol=; skip=2 tokens=4 delims=\t" %k in ('reg query "%%a" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ') do (
    if %k == "sas-" (reg delete "%%a")
)
)
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What doesn't work in your script? Not sure if typo, but your `%k` should be `%%k`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('
    reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"') do (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%b in ('
            reg query "%%a" /v "ProfileImagePath" 2^>nul ^| find "sas-"') do 
                rem reg delete "%%a"
                echo "%%a" >>C:\names.txt
)
```

I've based this on you querying the `ProfileImagePath` value, and deleting any of the keys that contain `sas-*` in the value. I've also put in a few line breaks you will have to remove (just for easy viewing on SO).

Please test this first (I've `echo`'d them to a text file at the moment), if you are happy with it then remove `rem` from the `reg delete` line.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked exactly as expected. Thanks a lot

Comment: @kedarbhusanikar Great, no probs

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it from a single `For` loop; *however, I do not particularly like the idea of removing profiles using this method.*

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=1-2*" %%A In ('Reg Query^
 "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" /S^
 /F ProfileImagePath /V 2^>Nul') Do (
    If Not "%%~A%%B"=="ProfileImagePathREG_EXPAND_SZ" (
        Set "_C=Reg Delete "%%A%%B"") Else (Set "_P=%%~C"
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        If Not "!_P:C:\Users\sas-=!"=="!_P!" Echo=!_C!
        EndLocal))
Timeout -1
```

If you're happy with the console output then remove `Echo=` from line 8 and delete line 10.